# Concatenate boost::array and std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, boost, concatenation

I have 2 boost arrays:

```
boost::array<int, 3> a = [1, 2, 3];
boost::array<int, 3> b = [4, 5, 6];
```

I need to concatenate them together with a string:

```
std::string this_string = "abc";
```

so that the end result would be "123abc456"

How would this be done?

Comment: The `boost::array` reference states says: "`operator[]` and `at()` are provided". There is `std::to_string()`. Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to use an ostringstream instance as a buffer:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;
for(auto x: a)
    buffer << x;
buffer << this_string;
for(auto x: b)
    buffer << x;
std::string result = buffer.str();
assert(result == "123abc456");
```

This is more efficient than concatenating strings and simple/straightforward to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload `'+'` for `boost::array` and `std::string` and use `std::to_string` something like following :

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::string operator+ ( const boost::array<T,N>& arr, const std::string & x )
{
    std::string s;
    for( const auto& i:arr)
    {
       s += std::to_string(i) ;
    }

    return s+x ;
}
```

See [*`here`*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6380d94c537ceba)

Comment: Why (on earth) would you overload the operator for this? This is going to lead to surprises. IMO you should consider overloading operators only if the behaviour is intuitively expectable. Especially in the generic way it's done now, is likely to cause some surprise when people do e.g. `s + array<char,1> { { '1' } }`

Comment: For the OP's question, you would also need to define `operator+ ( const std::string & x, const boost::array<T,N>& y )`. Aditionally, unless you use namespaces carefully, you risk this operator being used when you don't want it to. Please don't do this.

Comment: You cannot use namespaces carefully, because `boost::array` is in the `boost` namespace, and `std::string` is in `std`. ADL will have a field day with your "careful" operator :) (_Anyways, I think the OP's example "requires" this operatorm and not inverse as @utnapistim suggests_)

Comment: @sehe, without the other operator, how would you form the resulting string ("123abc456") with the input data given by the OP?

Comment: @utnapistim Sorry, I misread that you said "_also_ need to". I thought you meant it was the wrong one. In fact, both are needed for that sample, yes

Comment: @sehe I have that in the demo. Also I think it can be done in such away, so that it won't bind to a temporary boost::array to avoid surprises. Am I still missing something ?